# Итерация по двум спискам одновременно в шаблоне Джанго

Tags: python, django, шаблоны, jinja2

Нужно из двух списков подтянуть данные с одинаковыми индексами.
Пробую так:

`views.py:`

```
context = {
    'list_one': list_one,
    'list_two': list_two,
    'loops': range(8)
}
return render(request, 'some/under.html', context)
```

`under.html`

```
{% for i in loops %}
<li>
    <p>{{ list_one.i }}</p>
    <span class="count">{{ list_two.i }}%</span>
    <span class="index" style="width: {{ list_two.i }}%"></span>
</li>
{% endfor %}
```

Он действительно строит эту конструкцию 8 раз, но значения не вставляет. Просто пустое место оставляет.

Как можно решить этот вопрос?

Comment: А в `list_one` действительно есть поле `i`, оно же `list_one['i']`?

Comment: Т.е. я подозреваю, что `i` воспринимается буквально, а не как i-й элемент списка.

Comment: Если убрать цикл и проставить `list_one.0` и `list_two.0`, то все загружается. Пока пробую объединить эти списки в словарь. По всей видимости, он действительно неправильно воспринимает i

Comment: А если `list[i]`,  то есть без кавычек и явно?

Comment: Увы, индекс со скобками шаблонизатор Джанго не понимает. Понимает так: `list.index`. Сделал словарик `dict(zip(list_one,list_two))`, а в шаблоне прописал `{% for key, value in data.items %}`. Сработало, конечно, но сортировку растерял :)

Answer (score 2):

Судя по [аналогичному вопросу на enSO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21306134/iterating-over-multiple-lists-in-python-flask-jinja2-templates),  вам нужно сначала сделать `zip` списков (но не `dict(zip())`). Как-то так:

```
context = dict(pairs=zip(list_one, list_two))
return render(request, 'some/under.html', context)

{% for item_from_list_one, item_from_list_two in context.pairs %}
<li>
    <p>{{ item_from_list_one }}</p>
    <span class="count">{{ item_from_list_two }}%</span>
    <span class="index" style="width: {{ item_from_list_two }}%"></span>
</li>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: @jfs вы явно лучше разбираетесь, может ответ дадите?